# When copying and pasting the output of partial derivative of a function in Maxima, the pasted text stands instead for a total derivative

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

When I write the expression for the partial derivative of a function, `diff(f(x_1,x_2),x_1,1)`, for a function `f` created with `funmake(f,[x_1,x_2])`, the returned output is

[image]

However, when copying and pasting the output of the partial derivative, what I get instead is `'diff(f(x_1,x_2))`, which stands for the total derivative of the function `f` instead of the partial derivative:

[image]

Since total and partial derivatives are not the same thing, this is inappropriate. What is the reason for this behavior? How could it be fixed?

Comment: This is a bug in wxMaxima. My advice is to report it to the wxMaxima issue tracker: https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues I looked at the wxMaxima code for copying cells but I wasn't able to see what exactly is the problem or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Dodier wrote in the comments, this is a bug in wxMaxima. It is caused by the code that handles subscripts. (In your case, `_1` and `_2`). Subscript cells don't implement a function that is supposed to serialize the variable of differentiation.

To work around the issue, you can avoid using subscripts. Changing `x_1` and `x_2` to `x1` and `x2` works:

```
(%i1) diff(f(x1,x2),x1,1);     /* OK */
(%i2) diff(f(x_1,x_2),x_1,1);  /* NOT OK */
```

[image: output of the code]

Comment: I will try to fix the bug if I can.